# Telegram Bot (Python) получение последнего сообщения пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно получить 2 последних сообщения пользователя.
Как это сделать?
Не могу понять как получить доступ к истории сообщений, может в каком-то массиве по `chat_id` или типа того.
Что я пропустил?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, то такого метода не существует (по крайней мере в библиотеке PyTelegramBotAPI). Вместо этого можно записывать предпоследнее сообщение в базу данных (или файл) и последнее сообщение получать как обычно (message.text). И у Вас будет два последних сообщения.

Answer (score 1):

можешь все сообщения добавлять в список, а из него получить два последних значения так:

```
списокВсехСообщенийВПорядкеИхПолучения = список
последнееСообщение = списокВсехСообщенийВПорядкеИхПолучения[len(списокВсехСообщенийВПорядкеИхПолучения)]-1
предпоследнееСообщение = списокВсехСообщенийВПорядкеИхПолучения[len(списокВсехСообщенийВПорядкеИхПолучения)]-2
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).